# Weird waveforms for a transmitter circuit

Tags: transmitter, waveform

My book about digital logics ("Digital systems" of Ronald Tocci) provides a waveform which seems illogical to me about a transmitter circuit. This is the diagram of the circuit:

[image]

The inputs for the waveforms are [A] (0011), [B] (0110), [C] (1001), [D] (0111).
However, the outputs:

[image]

At the O3, I believe it must be 1110 instead of 0111 in the picture because the LSD always comes first to Z.

Comment: The waveform you show certainly does not appear to match the circuit conceptually but I have doubts about the shift registers on the transmit multiplexer.

Comment: Yes, if A came out reversed, then D should have, too. But it's a useless circuit anyway -- there's no attempt to make sure that the receiver is in sync with the transmitter and there are all kinds of timing issues with the logic. I can't imagine what they're trying to teach with this circuit...